# Как докачать остальные пакеты в VIsual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

При установке снял галочки с некоторых пакетов, можно ли после установки докачать прямо из VS? 
Переустанавливать IDE как-то не хочется.

Comment: В Windows меню есть Visual Studio Installer
или из меню VS2017: Средства-Получить средства и компоненты...

Comment: Запускайте установщик -> Изменить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Шаги:

- Запустите `Visual Studio Installer` (например, в меню пуск наберите это название)

  Появится окно:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Нажмите на `Modify` и выберите, что хотите установить или удалить:

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- После выбора нажмите на кнопку `Modify` в правом нижнем углу